# res.redirect("/"); This code is not working and shownig error 302 in chrome inspect

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, localhost

**not working showing error 302 in chrome inspect **

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
var items = [];
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  var today = new Date();`
  var options = {
    weekday:"long",
    day:"numeric",
    month:"long"
  };
  var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US" , options);
  res.render("list", {kindOfDay:day, newListItem:items });
});
app.post("/" , function(req, res){
 var item = req.body.newListItem;
  items.push(item)
  res.redirect("/");
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: 302 is a redirect and not an error. what do you expect if you make a request to `/` and get redirected to `/` ?

Comment: it should redirect to the home route but it is not doing that

Comment: Try `res.redirect(307,"/");`

Comment: res.redirect(307,"/"); is also not working